# Trying to send a image as byte[] from Spring backend to Angular frontend but:

Tags: arrays, angular, spring, rest, request

The backend code:

```
@GetMapping("datamatrix")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> generarDataMatrix(Long id) throws IOException {

    byte[] dataMatrixEnBytes = dataMatrix.generarDataMatrixImagen(id.toString(), id);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(dataMatrixEnBytes, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

In Postman the response is OK:

[image]

But in Angular...

[image]

Angular Code:

- Service:

```
generarDataMatrix( articulo: Articulo ): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpClient.get<any>( this.rootUrl + "datamatrix?id=" + articulo.id );
}
```

- Method caller:

```
generarDataMatrix() {
  this.dbServiceArticulo.generarDataMatrix( this.articuloSeleccionado )
    .subscribe( (res) => {console.log( "res" )});
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure the default `Content-Type` header is `application/json` which is why Angular's `HttpClient` is trying to parse the byte array as JSON. You can set the [`HttpHeaders`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders) for the request manually to the correct `Content-Type` for the response content.

Comment: Otherwise, you could set the `responseType` to `'blob'` for the request: `this.httpClient.get(this.rootUrl + '...', { responseType: 'blob' });`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the two solutions that D M has proposed to me and it has worked!

Pretty sure the default Content-Type header is application/json which is why Angular's HttpClient is trying to parse the byte array as JSON. You can set the HttpHeaders for the request manually to the correct Content-Type for the response content. – D M

Otherwise, you could set the responseType to 'blob' for the request: this.httpClient.get(this.rootUrl + '...', { responseType: 'blob' });. – D M